# Quantum circuits with only $\{CNOT, H\}$

Tags: resource-request, clifford-group

The Clifford circuit contains $\{CNOT, H, S\}$. I wonder, is there any paper that studied the quantum circuit only with $\{CNOT, H\}$? What's the name of this gate set?

Comment: Just a note that one gate set that is well studied is the {$H$, $CZ$} gateset. Especially in the study of graph states and MBQC. You can make a $CX$ into a $CZ$ trivially by applying a $H$ on the target qubit.

Comment: As far as I know, the graph state can be represented as a layer of H gate following with arbitrary CZ gate. The CZ gate corresponds to the edge in the graph state. Can the graph states represent all the quantum circuits constructed by {CNOT, H} gate set? Or the graph states only can represent a subset of {CNOT, H} circuits?